# First Acoustic Guitar

Tags: acoustic-guitar

(Though, this question may have been asked in past. I didn't find it, hence this new question)

I would like to play the guitar for myself as a hobby. But I am not sure, which guitar I need to go with as a beginning step. Will it be acoustic or electrical or any other ?

As this will be my first baby step into "Guitar-world", I need help to choose right guitar for me. Also, to begin with, which books or online/offline self-explanatory study material are available to learn. 
(My budget will be approx. Rs. 5000)

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're playing.

Typically, I would suggest you get an **acoustic guitar**. It's simple, portable, and versatile. But, if you're onto rock or metal, I would suggest you to get an **electric guitar.**

The acoustic guitar itself splits into *nylon strings* and *steel strings*. The nylon strings let you enjoy your style on jazz and classical. The steel strings let you enjoy your style on folk (and/or if you want to experiment with jazz or reggae). Some people said that the acoustic guitar got a big body, so it's not really that comfy on your grip. But you can buy a slim guitar, which sometimes costs a bit more.

The electric guitar itself splits into *hollow body* and *solid body*. Which you may find hollow body played on jazz and old classic blues and rock songs. While solid body you may find in pop culture, rock and other stuff like that. You may find the electric guitar is smaller and more skinny than the acoustic guitar to you to grip. But on some solid body guitars (like Les Paul), it may have more weigh.

It's up to you, but if you're just learning and want this as a hobby, I'm recommending the acoustic guitar.